# mvc4 how define layout zone/section for component library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i would build an application that is composite by component library(partial view), my problem is i haven't find a method to assign this component in a specific named zone of the layout.

i haven't find a solution and i haven't find sample code in google or article.

layout is a simply html5 and section/zone is div with own id.

Thank's

Comment: Did you try to set a `section` in the Layout page and use it on Views?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve it with `Section` of razor.

In _Layout page you can set the section:

```
<div id="ColumnSide">
    @RenderSection("MySectionName", false)
</div>
```

In your Views, you can set a content to this section

```
@section MySectionName {
   <text>
   Content Here..

   @Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView", model)
   </text>
}
```

And in the output result you will get a complete html where the section content has you have setted in the View.

Take a look at this artcile in the ScotGu's blog
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: thank for a reply, razor section is annidate in the layout code, my idea is that the section/zone is defined by web designer and i can assign to component property the zone to be rendered.

example web design define:

in my component i must assign the "zone" top

hope I was clear.

Comment: You can have many optional sections (as my awnser) on your layout page. So, your designer can set where he needs. the second bool parameter on the `RenderSection` method, identity if this section is required (set `false` to be optional).